# Asp chart Series Refresh with respect to time

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have a Asp Chart control.I added a Data source to my chart.Now i want to refresh my chart series for every one hour.I don't want to refresh the whole chart .I want to refresh the Chart Series only(dynamic chart).Help me to solve my problem.Answer rather than comments are Appreciated.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server"  onload="Chart1_Load" " BorderColor="#1A3B69">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series0" ChartType="Line" Color="#00ccff" XValueMember="Time" YValueMembers="Inuse" ChartArea="ChartArea1" Legend="Legend1"></asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom">
                    <AxisY Interval="3" Maximum="30" Minimum="0" Title="No of Bikes">
                    </AxisY>
                    <AxisX Title="Time">
                        <MajorGrid LineWidth="0" />
                    </AxisX>
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
            <Legends>
                <asp:Legend Name="Legend1"></asp:Legend>
            </Legends>
        </asp:Chart>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

C#:
 private void  chartload()
{
 Chart1.DataSource = dv;
 Chart1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a tick event for timer and set interval(in millisecond)

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="3600000"></asp:Timer>
```

and on c#

```
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //call chartload method
       chartload();
    }
```

Comment: In Your Method the whole chart will refresh .I want to refresh the series alone .@Amit Mishra